# How can I add a route to the index in my WordPress plugin using generate_rewrite_rules?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add the route `/.well-known/webfinger` to WordPress in a plugin, e.g. `http://exampleblog.com/.well-known/webfinger`. I'm using the `generate_rewrite_rules`, `parse_request`, and `query_vars` hooks to load up some code that should run when the URL is matched. Here's what I've got:

```
// includes/server/api.php
namespace api;

function generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $dot_well_known = array(
        '.well-known/webfinger' => 'index.php?well-known=webfinger'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $dot_well_known + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function check_flush_rules() {
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    if ( ! isset( $rules['.well-known/webfinger'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

function parse_request( $req ) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists( 'well-known', $req->query_vars ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( $req->query_vars['well-known'] === 'webfinger' ) {
        do_action( 'well_known_webfinger', $req->query_vars );
    }
}

function query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'well-known';
    return $query_vars;
}

// includes/init.php
namespace init;

require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'server/api.php';

add_action( 'my_plugin_load', function() {
    add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', '\api\generate_rewrite_rules' );
    add_action( 'parse_request', '\api\parse_request' );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', '\api\query_vars' );
    \api\check_flush_rules();
} );

// my_plugin.php (plugin entrypoint)
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/init.php';

function my_plugin_load() {
    do_action( 'my_plugin_load' );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_load' );
```

However, when I run a local WordPress instance (via `php -S localhost:8080`) I'm getting a `404 Not Found` status when I attempt to visit `http://localhost:8080/.well-known/webfinger`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was running WordPress via `php -S localhost:8080`. When I ran a proper Apache webserver locally `generate_rewrite_rules` worked as it was supposed to.